# How to put each word in a sentence inside a 2d array from a csv file

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read a text file and put each comma separated value in an array and put all of them inside a 2d array.But the code I have right now puts the whole line in the array

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)));
        int rows = 3;
        int columns = 1;
        String[][] myArray = new String[rows][columns];
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" " + ",");
                for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                    myArray[i][j] = line[j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
```

This is the text file:

```
A6,A7
F2,F3
F6,G6
```

## Output

`[[A6,A7], [F2,F3], [F6,G6]]`

## Expected Output

`[[A6],[A7],[F2],[F3],[F6],[G6]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the entire 2D array instead of just each item.

Here are several alternatives.

- Use [Files.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)) to stream the file.
- splitting on a comma creates the 1D array of two elements for each line
- `flatMap` that to stream each item.
- that `map` that to an array of one item.
- then just store them in a 2D array.

```
String[][] array = null;
try {
    array = Files.lines(Path.of("f:/MyInfo.txt"))
            .flatMap(line->Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
                 .map(item->new String[]{item}))
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
if (array != null) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
}
```

prints

```
[[A6], [A7], [F2], [F3], [F6], [G6]]
```

Here is an approach similar to yours.

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("f:/MyInfo.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] arr = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        for (String item : arr) {
            list.add(new String[]{item});
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is no `deepToString` for `Lists` so you either iterate it or convert to a 2D array.

```
String[][] ar = list.toArray(String[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ar));
```

prints

```
[[A6], [A7], [F2], [F3], [F6], [G6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to double the rows size and for each line just put one element and increment the i++

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the result array is not correct.

Since you want the end result should look like this, `[[A6],[A7],[F2],[F3],[F6],[G6]]`, it is a 2-dimensional array with one row and six columns.

Considering it, I have changed and simplified your code.

```
int rows = 3;
String[][] r = new String[1][rows * 2];

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/path/to/the/file") 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] current = line.split(",");
    r[0][i++] = current[0];
    r[0][i++] = current[1];
}
```